# Is there a way to display total members, bot and humans?

Tags: discord.py

I cannot figure out how to calculate how many total members, bots and humans there are in the guild. I can find the total members, but can't figure out how to get the total bots and humans.

Answer (score 1):

[`Guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.members) gives you a list of [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member)s in this Guild, which have a [`.bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.User.bot) attribute. This is a `boolean` that indicates whether or not the member is a bot.

That should be enough for you to figure out the rest - I'm not gonna give you the code for it without you at least doing a *little bit* of effort figuring it out on your own first. It's only two lines.

Answer (score 0):

To get the member count, use: `guild.member_count`. Note that you need to specify `Intents.members` when initializing your bot. This is a discord limitation.

Source: [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.member_count)